# how do you add site categories on a database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, web

I'm working on an entertainment website That recommends shows for users and id like to add multiple categories for a single show so i have a database table named shows which has info about the shows for example preview image, name, start date e.t.c . i have another table for categories so im asking how should i plan the database in a way that every show has its own set of categories.

Comment: create another table for the relation between `show` and `category` just like `show_categories` and in that table use `show_id` and `category_id`

Comment: Do you require sub-categories as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create another table for the relation between `show` and `category`  in that table use `show_id` and `category_id`

[image: Sample Database Structure]

inorder to get the categories of a show you just want to join `show,category,show_category` tables.

Comment: can you post the sql query you need to get categories of show id 1?

Comment: `select * from show_category A join category B on A.category_id = B.category_id where A.show_id = 1`

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a pivot table.

```
CREATE TABLE `categories` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `categories` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'Kids and Family'),
(2, 'Adult Content'),
(3, 'Teen'),
(4, 'Cartoon'),
(5, 'Unrated'),
(6, 'Movie'),
(7, 'Series');

CREATE TABLE `shows` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `network` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `shows` (`id`, `name`, `network`) VALUES
(1, 'The Simpsons', 'Fox'),
(2, 'Seinfeld', 'NBC');

CREATE TABLE `show_categories` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `show_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `show_categories` (`id`, `show_id`, `category_id`) VALUES
(1, 1, 3),
(2, 1, 4),
(3, 1, 7),
(4, 2, 3),
(5, 2, 7);

ALTER TABLE `categories`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `shows`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `show_categories`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `categories`
  MODIFY `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=8;

ALTER TABLE `shows`
  MODIFY `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=3;

ALTER TABLE `show_categories`
  MODIFY `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=6;
```

Then you can write a JOIN statement like this to get the categories for a given show:

```
SELECT a.name as 'show',c.name as 'category' FROM shows a LEFT JOIN show_categories b ON a.id=b.show_id LEFT JOIN categories c ON c.id=b.category_id
```

You can run the above in the sql fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/12767/1/0).